# AWS Identity Pool Google Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

I am creating a basic web app with react that uses a google login button and AWS Cognito to authorize tokens that will give users access to certain AWS resources. Here is my thought process:

1. User signs in with Google Login (User is Authenticated)
2. Google token is sent to Identity Pool
3. The user is recognized in Identity pool (User is Authorized)
4. The user gains access to AWS resources like S3 based on IAM role

I have several questions that correspond to this:

1. I need to create a custom UI and the hosted user pool with google login is not an option. Without using the hosted UI, how do see all of my users logged into the app?
2. How do I set up different IAM based on different users? For instance, Sally has read and write permissions to S3, but Bob only has read permissions, how do I only assign IAM roles to specific users? Do I need to write lambda functions or can rule within the identity pool to accomplish this task?

Any information on this topic would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For question number 2, you can use CLI `aws cognito-identity` or AWS SDK for your language of choice.

For question number 3, you can do that using AWS Lambda, but it is simpler when you use Cognito User Pool group with different IAM role for each group.